# What works for POST doesn't work for AJAX. But why?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This code works perfectly, posts the JSON correctly onto the other side

```
$.post("/admin/httpaction/verifyCertificate",
                    {_token: '{{csrf_token()}}', certificationNumber: certificateID},
                    function(data){
                        console.debug(data);
                       alert("posted!");
                    }, "json");
```

This code doesn't encode the JSON correctly, resulting in internal server error. It must be something I'm doing wrong with the JSON encoding. But what?

```
 var verifyObj = {
                _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
                certificationNumber: certificateID
            }

    $.ajax({
              url: '/admin/httpaction/verifyCertificate',
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'post',
              contentType: 'application/json',
              data: verifyObj,
              processData: false,
              success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                 alert("success");
              },
              error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                  alert("error " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown );
               }
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you set `processData` to `false`, `verifyObj` is not encoded. See `$.ajax processData` spec:

> processData (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object
>   (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and
>   transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a
>   DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Setting it to true should solve your problem.